# 2 navigation tab bars jquery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, jquery-ui

It's pretty easy, i want to have 2 nav tags within my html page. Both supporting the tabs-widget from JqueryUI

this is how to create one tabbed navigation:

```
<nav id="tabs">
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li id="menu_about"><a href="#aboutme">All About Me</a></li>
                    <li id="menu_portfolio"><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li id="menu_work_experience"><a href="#work">Werkervaring</a></li>
                    <li id="menu_skills"><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
                </ul>
 <div id="#aboutme">content bla bla bla </div>
</nav>
```

But how to do get two of these?

```
<nav id="tabs">
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li id="menu_about"><a href="#aboutme">All About Me</a></li>
                    <li id="menu_portfolio"><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li id="menu_work_experience"><a href="#work">Werkervaring</a></li>
                    <li id="menu_skills"><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
                </ul>
 <div id="#aboutme">content bla bla bla </div>
</nav>
<nav id="tabs2">
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li id="menu_about"><a href="#aboutme">All About Me</a></li>
                    <li id="menu_portfolio"><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li id="menu_work_experience"><a href="#work">Werkervaring</a></li>
                    <li id="menu_skills"><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
                </ul>
 <div id="#aboutme">content bla bla bla </div>
</nav>
```

As this results into the first nav tag to be tabbed, and the 2nd nav-tag not to be tabbed.

I've tried to change tabs2 to tabs aswell. But that didn't work as aspected.

Please help me out!

EDIT

At the moment I Don't have any javascript written. This is because i can see which one are tabbed and which arent.

The ones that are tabbed get this to show source code in my browser:

```
<nav id="tabs" class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
                <ul id="menu" class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" role="tablist">
                    <li id="menu_about" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-active ui-state-active" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-controls="aboutme" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" aria-selected="true"><a href="#aboutme" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-1">All About Me</a></li>
                    <li id="menu_portfolio" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="portfolio" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2" aria-selected="false"><a href="#portfolio" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-2">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li id="menu_work_experience" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="work" aria-labelledby="ui-id-3" aria-selected="false"><a href="#work" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-3">Werkervaring</a></li>
                    <li id="menu_skills" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="skills" aria-labelledby="ui-id-4" aria-selected="false"><a href="#skills" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-4">Skills</a></li>
                </ul>
</nav>
```

The 2nd one don't have those classes at the html elements.
Which he does need to have to work as a tab.

Comment: What does your javascript look like?

Comment: Show your javascript where you initialize the tabs.

Comment: At this moment i don't have any javascript on, yet i can see the first one are tabbed, and the 2nd ones aren't. This is because the nav and ul and li elements get all the widgets as class in it.

Comment: You've got duplicate ID's anyway, and also an invalid ID (one starting with a `#`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Tabs | jQuery UI

### JS

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs, #tabs2" ).tabs();
  });
```

### HTML

```
 <nav  id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">All About Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Skills</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. </p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis.</p>
    <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus.</p>
  </div>
</nav >
 
    
 
<nav  id="tabs2">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">All About M 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Portfolio 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Skills 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. </p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis.</p>
    <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus.</p>
  </div>
</nav >
```

Example from jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KrtXt/2/

Comment: I did the js-part in the html file and it works.
Now i'm putting it in the seperate jsfile and it doesn't work?

Comment: How are you calling your JS file?  View source and click on your JS file link to make sure your it loading properly.